# Can Lightning Dash affect the same enemy more than once?

Tags: feats, pathfinder-2e, kineticist

In the new Rage of Elements, the 4th level Kineticist feat allows you to move 30ft through creatures. I was wondering if there was any way to trigger the damage on the same creature more than once. Like, if the enemy occupies more than 1 square, or if I pass through the enemy more than once during that movement. Is there any instance of that happening?

> [LIGHTNING DASH](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=4211)
>
> For an instant, you transform yourself into a being of pure lightning and
> fly forward, shocking anyone in your way. You propel yourself forward
> in a 30-foot line. You can move through creatures during this
> movement, and this movement doesn't trigger reactions that are
> triggered by movement. Each creature you move through takes 2d12
> electricity damage with a basic Reflex save against your class DC. You
> return to your normal form in the final square of the line. If you're
> in the air, you fall unless you have a fly Speed.
>
> Rage of Elements, page 24.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Not under normal circumstances

The feat states

> Each creature you move through takes 2d12 electricity damage

Nothing there talks about the creature getting the damage for each square, so it won't if it is larger and occupies multiple squares.

> You propel yourself forward in a 30-foot line.

Since you only can move forward 30 feet in a straight line, it would require very unusual circumstances to be able to pass through the same creature twice, as normally the creatures cannot move around while it is your turn and while this effect plays out. The way this is written, you cannot stop in-between to do other things. The effect is that you propel yourself the full 30 feet. It also has no language about rebounding from walls, like old-school D&D lightning bolts, so presumably, if you hit a wall behind the creature, you just stop. Maybe, if there was a portal right behind the creature that gated you back in front if it, you might continue your straight movement to hit it a second time. But there is no reusable effect that would allow you to do so reliably.

Even then, it would probably be up to the GM if the same creature could be affected twice. As written a creature you move through takes the stated damage, not a creature as you move through it, or each time you move through it. No matter how often you move through a creature, it remains just "a creature you move through". Although, if I were your DM and there were portal shenanigans going on, I'd allow it, its both cool and makes narrative sense.

Comment: "The way this is written, this is different from normal movement where you can stop in-between to do other things." Thats also not true for normal movement in Pathfinder 2e.

Comment: @Patta, I checked and saw you do not have to walk the full speed in a stride, but I think you mean you cannot move less, then act, and resume striding, which this here would require. I changed that sentence to correct it.